# How to execute a .java file on clicking a jbutton in jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

On clicking the jbutton in a jframe, I want Start.java file to be executed;what to do?
The Start.java is executing well. I want the same execution to be done when clicked on jbutton in jframe, please help me out.

My jframe code has jbutton

```
private void jButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {   

    // i want to execute Start.java file on clicking the button

     Start s = new Start();
     String in = s.getTxt;
     System.out.println(in);
    repaint();
 }
```

My Start.java file is :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Start extends JPanel{

public String getTxt;
public Start()
{

 final  JTextField jf = new JTextField(20);
 jf.setBounds(30, 30, 250, 30);
 final JButton j1 = new JButton("OK");
 j1.setBounds(80, 80, 100, 30);
 setLayout(null);

 add(jf);
 add(j1);

   j1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                        getTxt = jf.getText();
                        System.out.println(getTxt);

                    }
                   });
  }


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Interest");
    f.getContentPane().add(new Start());
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(310,250));
    f.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(310,250));
    f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(310,250));

    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you thought about adding the instance of `Start` you your existing container?  Maybe using a `CardLayout`?  Have you thought of creating a new `JFrame` and adding your instance of `Start` to it or maybe use a `JDialog`?

Comment: i wanted to try adding Start instance in Jframe but i am not so sure about moving from one jframe to another.. i ll try adding it to the existing container..Thank u

Answer (score 4):

So, based on what you seem to be doing in your code, I would strongly recommend that you have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), the main reason for this is, a modal dialog will cause the execution of your program to stop at the point where the dialog is made visible and resume when it's closed, this way, allowing you to inspect the values the user might have changed.

So, when I first tried to get your program to work, this is what happened...

[image: Bad]

So, after digging into your code, I noticed you'd done `setLayout(null);`.  This is going to keep on coming back to haunt you and I strongly recommend that you don't do this and learn how to use the layout management API.

So, I jumped into you code and add a layout manager...

```
public class Start extends JPanel {

    public String getTxt;

    public Start() {

        final JTextField jf = new JTextField(20);
        final JButton j1 = new JButton("OK");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        add(jf, gbc);
        add(j1, gbc);

        j1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                getTxt = jf.getText();
                System.out.println(getTxt);

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Interest");
        f.getContentPane().add(new Start());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(310, 250));
        f.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(310, 250));
        f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(310, 250));

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now I get...

[image: better]

Okay, but now there's two buttons, and unless the user clicks the middle button, the text is never set!

The fact is, for this kind of thing, you don't need the button! You just need a method which can return the current text of the `JTextField`, for example...

```
public class Start extends JPanel {

    final JTextField jf = new JTextField(20);

    public Start() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        add(jf, gbc);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return jf.getText();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Interest");
        f.getContentPane().add(new Start());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(310, 250));
        f.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(310, 250));
        f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(310, 250));

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And then I can use...

[image: Done!]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("Surprise");
            add(btn);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Start start = new Start();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, start, "Surprise", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    System.out.println(start.getText());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }
}
```

to show it!

I'd strongly recommend that you take the time to have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)